# How to replace nulls with zeros in pivot query sql for fact table in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pivot, pivot-table, databricks

I see lots of solutions for how to do this where there is a column being queried including the following...

[how to Replace null with zero in pivot SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241874/how-to-replace-null-with-zero-in-pivot-sql-query)

[Oracle 11g SQL - Replacing NULLS with zero where query has PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096646/oracle-11g-sql-replacing-nulls-with-zero-where-query-has-pivot)

[Replacing null values in dynamic pivot sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510216/replacing-null-values-in-dynamic-pivot-sql-query)

etc.,etc.,etc.,

But how do you replace the nulls in a pivot query when your are creating a fact table for the existence of a condition.

For example, in Databricks:
How do I replace the nulls for the following

**Setup**

```
drop table if exists patient_dx;

create table patient_dx (patient_id string, dx string);

insert into patient_dx values
  ('Bob', 'cough'),
  ('Donna', 'cough'),
  ('Jerry', 'cough'),
  ('Bob', 'feaver'),
  ('Donna', 'head ache')
;
```

**Query:**

```
select * from (
  select
    patient_id,
    dx,
    cast (1 as int) cnt
  from
    patient_dx
)
pivot (
  max(cnt)
  for dx in ('cough','feaver','head ache')
)
;
```

**Result**

[image]

I've tried several permutations of:

```
cast(0 + cast(coalesce(sum(coalesce(cnt,0)),0) as int) as int) as cnt
```

To no avail

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### You have to use coalesce or NOT NULL to substitute null values in select query.

Check below if it helps:

---

Try this:

```
spark.sql("""
select
 patient_id,
 CASE 
 when cough is NOT NULL THEN cough
 else 0
 END as cough,
 CASE 
 when feaver is NOT NULL THEN feaver
 else 0
 END as feaver,
 CASE 
 when `head ache` is NOT NULL THEN `head ache`
 else 0
 END as `head ache`
 from ( 
select * from patient
)
PIVOT(
  Count(dx)
  for dx in ('cough','feaver','head ache')
)
;
""").show()
```

The output will be:

| patient_id | cough | feaver | head ache |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Donna | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Jerry | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Bob | 1 | 1 | 0 |

if you want it to be dynamic

```
dist=spark.sql("select collect_set(dx) from patient;").toPandas()
val=spark.sql("""
select
 patient_id,
 coalesce(cough,0) as `cough`,
 coalesce(feaver,0) as `feaver`,
 coalesce(`head ache`,0) as `head ache`
 from ( 
select * from patient
)
PIVOT(
  Count(dx)
  for dx in """
+
str(tuple(map(tuple, *dist.values))[0])
+
"""
)
;
""")
```

Comment: This is awesome!!! I was hoping for a pure sql solution but I think this will solve at least some of my problems.  I'll give it a try and let you know how I make out.  Thanks!